# Comprobar input vacío

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy programando en *PHP* y *MySQL* y tengo un formulario con datos personales y un botón *submit* para guardar. Entonces quiero validar que el *input* del root de la persona no este vacío, y por tanto no deje guardar.

Tengo esta función *JavaScript*:

```
function validar(){
    if ($('#txtrut').text() == "") {
        alert('Ingrese rut');
        return false;
    }
};
```

La ejecuto en el evento *onclick* del *submit*, pero me muestra siempre el *alert*, esté vacío el input o no.

¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?

Comment: Debería ser `.val(),` no `.text()`

Comment: También puedes eliminar la etiqueta `php`, esto no parece estar relacionado con PHP, ¿o sí? Usted sabe que la verificación del lado del cliente no es la mejor y se debe usar un método del lado del servidor.

Answer (score 12):

Después de ver cuatro respuestas, veo que no han utilizado una propiedad bastante común y útil en estos casos: [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/length)

```
function validar() {
  if ($('#txtrut').val().length == 0) {
    alert('Ingrese rut');
    return false;
  }
}
```

Esta propiedad simplemete nos da la longitud del valor que tenga el input, en caso que haya un espacio, las otras respuestas fallarían.

Esta podría ser la respuesta más simple, dependiendo del tipo de validación que quieras hacer en el campo como tal.

Comment: ¿Pero si usas `length`, no toma espacios dado por la barra espaciadora?

Answer (score 10):

Usa esto en tu HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="nombre" required/>
```

El atributo `required` específica que el input debe completarse antes de poder enviar el formulario.

Para ver la compatibilidad con los diferentes navegadores, vea [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp).

Answer (score 6):

Para capturar el valor de un input se utiliza .val()

Ejemplo :

```
var campo = $('#id_del_input').val();
```

y Luego lo validas,

```
if(campo === ''){
 alert("El campo esta vacío");
return false;
}else{
 //Las validaciones que necesitas hacer
}
```

Answer (score 4):

La tarea en si no es compleja, no veo que al día de hoy se requiera en lo absoluto de JQuery así que podemos proceder con el lenguaje en su estado puro así

- Obtenemos y asignamos en variables a:

  - botón que procesa el envío del formulario
  - `input` en el cual el usuario puede escribir el `root`
  - Un eventual `div` donde el usuario recibirá un mensaje indicando el estado de su acción
- Posterior dentro de una clase inicializamos por su constructor a las 2 propiedades requeridas que serían tanto el `input` como el botón
- Posterior dentro de un método asignamos que la propiedad que representa al botón tenga un *listener* al evento `click` para verificar cuando el usuario quiera enviar el formulario
- Prevenimos el comportamiento por *defecto* por medio del parámetro `event`
- Después haciendo uso del operador ternario verificamos si el `input` viene vacío

  - Ojo que aquí nos apoyamos de la función [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/Trim) para eliminar espacios en blanco tanto al inicio como al fin del `value` ingresado
- Dependiendo si esta lleno o no entonces por medio de `innerHTML` agregamos un texto al `div` que indicará el estado del procesamiento del formulario
- Al final generamos la instancia y con el objeto accedemos al método que nos de dicha funcionalidad

**Propuesta de código**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form action="">
        <input type="text" id="root" />
        <button id="btn-envio">Enviar datos</button>
      </form>
      <div id="aviso"></div>
    <script>
        let rootInput    = document.getElementById("root")
        let botonEnvio   = document.getElementById("btn-envio")
        let aviso        = document.getElementById("aviso")
        
        class Formulario {
          constructor(rootInput, botonEnvio) {
            this.rootInput    = rootInput
            this.botonEnvio   = botonEnvio
          }
          
          validaElementos() {
            this.botonEnvio.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
              event.preventDefault();
              (this.rootInput.value.trim() === "")
                ? aviso.innerHTML = `El root es un valor requerido`
                : aviso.innerHTML = `Formulario procesado con ${this.rootInput.value}`
            })
          }
        }
      
        let formularioValidadoUno = new Formulario(rootInput, botonEnvio)
        formularioValidadoUno.validaElementos()
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3):

### Validación de `input text`:

Para empezar, crearemos una función que devuelva un **booleano**, es decir, un verdadero y falso. La denominaremos `validar()`:

```js
const validar = ( selector, num = 4 ) => {
  // Instrucciones
};
```

Donde `selector`, es el selector que pasará como argumento de la función `validar()` como una cadena para obtener el elemento a evaluar y `num` la cantidad mínima de caracteres requeridos para considerar válido el valor del elemento obtenido. En este caso, un `input text`.

Por lo tanto, teniendo claro lo anteriormente expuesto, definámosla completa:

```js
const validar = ( selector, num = 4 ) => {
  // Se verifica si selector es una cadena:
  if ( typeof selector !== "string" )
    return false;

  // Se obtiene el elemento mediante el selector:
  let text = document.querySelector( selector );

  // Se verifica si el elemento obtenido es nulo.
  // Si es nulo devolverá «false»:
  if ( text === null )
    return false;

  // Se eliminan los caracteres y se determina
  // que la cantidad mínima sea «num». Es decir,
  // que la caja de texto no se encuentre vacía y 
  // la cantidad mínima de caracteres sea «num»:
  if ( ! (text.value.trim().length < num) )
    return true;

  return false;
};
```

De acuerdo al ejemplo anterior, la función `validar()` devolverá `false` por defecto. Si la cadena es válida, entonces devolverá `true`.

#### ¿De qué manera se podrá utilizar la función?

La función `validar()`, tal y como lo indica su nombre validará si la caja de texto se encuenta vacía y que la cantidad mínima de caracteres sea 4. Es decir:

```js
if ( validar( "#texto" ) ) {
  // Instrucciones
}
```

Si la caja de texto cumple las validaciones requeridas la función devolverá `true`, de lo contrario, devolverá `false`.

Si bien, no se ha definido de la forma:

```js
if ( validar( "#texto", 4 ) ) {
  // Instrucciones
}
```

Es porque por defecto, el segundo parámetro tiene como valor el número `4`, a menos que se desee cambiar a un valor diferente del mencionado.

### Implementación

Para su implementación, se asumirá que se dispone del siguiente formulario:

```html
<form action="un_archivo.php" method="post" id="formulario">
  <input type="text" name="texto" id="texto" />
  <button type="submit">Realizar prueba</button>
</form>
```

Para ello, simplemente capturaremos el evento `submit` y detenemos el envío del formulario si la caja de texto no cumple con las validaciones que le hemos indicado:

```js
const formulario = document.querySelector("#formulario");

formulario.onsubmit = e => {
  if ( !validar("#texto") ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert( "No cumple con las validaciones indicadas" );
  }
}
```

Donde `e.preventDefault()` detiene el envío del formulario y `alert()` la función con la que le recordaremos al usuario que la caja de texto no cumple con las validaciones.

**Hay que recordar que:**

- `if ( validar( "#texto" ) )`, significa: "*si el valor de la caja de texto es válida, entonces..."*.
- `if ( !validar( "#texto" ) )`, significa: "*si la caja de texto se encuentra vacía o no es válida, entonces..."*.

Esto es, en función del tipo de validaciones que hemos definido en la función `validar()`.

#### Probando código:

Ahora, probemos el código completo:

```js
const validar = ( selector, num = 4 ) => {
  if ( typeof selector !== "string" )
    return false;
    
  let text = document.querySelector( selector );
  if ( text === null )
    return false;
    
  if ( ! (text.value.trim().length < num) )
    return true;

  return false;
};


const formulario = document.querySelector("#formulario");
formulario.onsubmit = e => {
  if ( !validar("#texto") ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert( "No cumple con las validaciones indicadas" );
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" id="formulario">
  <input type="text" name="texto" id="texto" />
  <button type="submit">Realizar prueba</button>
</form>
```

**Importante:** debe tomarse en cuenta que esta publicación es orientativa. La idea es dar una idea general de cómo podría validarse una caja de texto, sin embargo, pueden existir soluciones más simples y elegantes que ésta.

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener el valor del `input` se utiliza `$('input.id').val()` y esto resuelve tu problema.

**Como anexo:**

El `$('#id').text()` es utilizado para elementos como `divs`, `labels` entre otros para obtener el texto incluido en ellos.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
$('#pri').html($('p').text());
$('#ter').text($('p').html());
$('#seg').html($('input').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="texto prueba">
<p style="display:none;"><span>lol</span> Texto de un parráfo oculto</p>
<br>
<label id="pri"></label>
<br><label id="seg"></label>
<br><label id="ter"></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Estás utilizando [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), capturando el valor del `input="text"` (`$('#txtrut').val()`) puedes hacer la validación como lo deseas, te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
function validar(){
  console.log();
    if ($('#txtrut').val() == "") {
        alert('Vacio');
        return false;
    }else{
      alert('lleno');
      
    }
};

function validarSoloJs(){
 valor = document.getElementById("txtrut1").value;
 if( valor != "" ) {
  alert('Lleno');
 }else{
   alert('Vacío');
 }
}
```

```html
<!-- Libreria JQuery --> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Validacion con JQuery</label>
<br>
<input type="text" id="txtrut" >
<button onclick="validar();">validar</button>
<!-- Validacion con javascript -->
<br>
<label>Validación con Javascript</label>
<br>
<input type="text" id="txtrut1" >
<button onclick="validarSoloJs();">validar</button>
```

Puedes documentarte mas en [librosweb](http://librosweb.es/libro/javascript/capitulo_7/validacion.html)

Comment: gracias ,pero cada vez me sale el mensaje "lleno", aunque este vacio el input

Comment: Mira modifique la respuesta prueba con alguna de las dos opciones, recuerda que para que ejecute el código [tag:jquery] necesitas importar la librería, espero te funcione.

Answer (score 1):

Aquí te dejo esto, espero te pueda servir:

[Ejemplo Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/gsdqwamyfl9qsSqwbjGu?p=preview)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var boton_rut;
  
  boton_rut = $('#rut_check');
  
  boton_rut.on('click', function(){
    
     var valor_input, valor_rut;
    
    valor_input = $('#rut_txt');
    valor_rut = valor_input.val();
    
    if(valor_rut.trim() === ''){
      alert('El input esta vacio');
    }else{
      alert("El input tiene informacion");
    }
    
  }); 
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div>
      Rut:<input type="text" id="rut_txt">
      <button id="rut_check">Verificar</button>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: perfecto! muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Esta es la Forma mas sencilla de hacerlo con JavaScript

```
<script>function inputVacio(){ var valor = document.getElementById('Idinput').value;  if(valor == '')alert('esta vacio') }</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre no mostrar el botón submit hasta que el campo input contenga algún valor introducido por el usuario.

Le agregaría un "placeholder" para avisarle al usuario que es un campo que requiere ser completado.

Y usaría la librería JQuery.

**¡Importante!**

La librería JQuery debe cargarse LUEGO de haber cargado todos los estilos de la página.
Es decir, cargar todas las librerías CSS o estilos ANTES de cargar las librerías JQuery.js necesarias.

```
/* PRIMERO VERIFICAMOS QUE TODAS LAS LIBRERIAS CSS SE CARGUEN ANTES
QUE LAS LIBRERIAS JQUERY */
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
/* Y LUEGO... */
<script src="/la_ruta_de_tu_dominio/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#submit").hidden();
       $("#id_input").change( function() {
          if ($('#id_input').val() === '') {
              $("#submit").hidden();
              alert("El campo esta vacío");
          } else {
              $("#id_submit").show();
          }
       });
   });
</script>
```

De todos modos, y antes de enviar información a la base de datos MySQL, es necesario comprobar lo ingresado en el INPUT desde PHP para evitar inyecciones SQL.
Nunca será 100% segura la validación desde JS del lado del cliente para eso porque puede ser modificada antes.

Answer (score 1):

*Traducción de [una respuesta en Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59994973), publicada por [zfrisch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3700849/zfrisch)*

Como lo mencione en el comentario anterior, deberías usar `val()` y no `text()`. Sin embargo, para estar absolutamente seguro y realizar una verificación más coherente, debe usar el valor como condicional `length`.

```
function validar(){
    if (!$('#txtrut').val().length) {
        alert('Ingrese rut');
        return false;
    }
};
```

**Nota:** Tenga en cuenta que esta verificación seguirá aceptando espacios en blanco. Para evitar eso, hasta cierto punto, puede usar el método `trim`.

```
function validar(){
    if (!$('#txtrut').val().trim().length) {
        alert('Ingrese rut');
        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

La forma adecuada de validar un input si no esta vacio es limpiado los espacios en blanco.

JS:

```
<script>
  function validar() {
    var validarRut = $('#txtrut')
      .val()
      .split(' ')
      .join('');

    if (validarRut == '') {
      alert('Debes infresar tu numbero Rut');
      return false;
    }

    alert('Ok');
  }
</script>
```

Ejemplo HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtrut" placeholder="Ingrese numero rut..." />
<button type="submit" onclick="validar()">Validar</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Valida que no exista campos vacios dentro del cuadro de texto**

```js
if ($('#txtrut').val() != null ||  $('#txtrut').val()!=undefined  || $('#txtrut').val()!="") {    alert('el cuadro de texto esta vacio.');}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtrut" value="">
```

ya luego realizas el retorno a False

Answer (score -1):

Daniel con esta linea

```
if(valorEtiqueta === ''){
        swal( "Oops!! No se puede dejar vacío el campo" ,"Favor de capturar al menos un ACTIVO..","error" );
        return false;
        } else if(expreg.test(valorEtiqueta)){..
```

aquí cabe mencionar que aparte de esta validación tengo una expresión regular que solo permite ingresar una secuencia de dígitos predefinida ya sea desde el teclado o con una pistola lectora de código de barras. Hasta el momento me ha funcionado bastante bien y de una manera muy sencilla.

En el HTML puedes agregar `<input required="required">` y para habilitar o deshabilitar el botón hago esto:

```
 `<button type="submit" name="btnCotejar" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnCotejar"  disabled="disable" >Cotejar</button>`
```

Por default deshabilitado y con esta simple línea que depende de la creación de inputs que contienen los códigos de barras capturados `$('#btnCotejar').attr('disabled', false);` habilita el botón para poder hacer el submit es cuestión que lo adaptes a tu desarrollo.